# How long do standees stay in a course when playing online?

Tags: super-mario-bros-wonder

When in a course, we can drop a standee anywhere we can crouch (no slopes). And it seems like we're limited to leaving one standee behind. Any other standees you drop, the previous one will disappear.

But what if I drop one, and not leave another for the rest of my time playing?

Does a standee stay up for as long as I'm in the course (and online) or do they have a time out? Does it persist for other players when I inevitably leave the course?

Answer (score 1):

> Does it persist for other players when I inevitably leave the course?

Yes, definitely. I just got the notification that somebody used my standee from a previous level.

> Any other standees you drop, the previous one will disappear.

This seems true only inside the same level. If you place a standee on a level which is then completed, you can drop another standee on another level without removing the previous one. You can get the above-mentioned notification even when a standee was already placed on another level.

This is from my personal exprience.

They do must have a set lifespan that let them disappear, which is unclear at the moment.

Comment: It's a little more complicated because each world has it's own 'room'. You can stand in a level and you'll notice a max of 4 players, and nobody enters the room after those 4 finish or quit. Also, if you continue playing the same level, you can bump into your own standee even if you've left or finished the level.

Comment: @dustytrash yes, the point is the standee doesn't disappear when you leave the level

Comment: To reinforce standees staying after you beat a level, in one video (Spoilers for final stage) you can see Peach drop a standee at [1:51:25](https://youtu.be/xTaRZGH30Jo?t=6685). Later on after Peach clears the level, a standee is stil present at [1:52:34](https://youtu.be/xTaRZGH30Jo?t=6753)